# problem : cant convert .py file to exe , using pyinstaller, py2exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, cmd, pyinstaller

8 version of python that include  pip, pyinstaller, pygame, py2exe. I tried a lot of solutions, after a search in google and this website. I tried to:

- convert my .py file to exe --> dont sucssed
- add the path to the enviorment variables --> dont work
- install pyinstaller from the cmd, and then run the command `pyinstaller --onefile -w "myfile.py"` --> dont work, the same with work shell
- install the py2exe from the cmd and then with to convert to exe --> don't work
- reinstall --> dont work

Everything tells me that the problem is my version(3.8) of python, because this version don't support yet on the pyinstaller(acording to what I read).

**cmd Error:**

> File C:\Users\zahta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
> raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
> win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system')

**work shell Error:**

> File "C:\Users\zahta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
> raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
> win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryEx', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system')

After typing the command in cmd nothing happened. After the WorkShell - dist folder created but empty without change my python version what can I do to fix it to get a excutable file of my game?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a beginner like you, but according to my research you are using python which is downloaded from windows store, which creates permission errors. Try deleting windows store python and download it from the official python website. Source: http://pyinstaller.47505.x6.nabble.com/1920-LoadLibraryExW-The-file-cannot-be-accessed-by-the-system-td2954.html

Comment: yes , I changed it to anaconda now it better than before but I still have problems with this . After that I tried with pyinstller i have Error :NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type Failed to excute script after i used cx_Freeze -> I cant install it with anaconda , when I install from the anaconda promot , it give success feedback , but the pycharm dont recognize it . It give Error when trying to install from the setting . I need help, if there is only this two tools to make py to exe , so what I can do if they both dont work?

tnx

Comment: I don't know much about converting to exe, but you should check which distribution is pycharm using. Because most of the times if I'm right, pycharm uses the official distribution if it was downloaded first. Refer to this article on how to add the distribution if it is not added and select. In the process you will automatically get to know which distribution pycharm is using. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html

Comment: I just checked it , and download new one , now Im using anaconda3 as interpeter .But it not the problem I think but tnx  , I want is to make py a exe , I worked on this code a lot ..the same Error again and again .. what can I do ?

Comment: You should now use cx_freeze with pycharm again. Hopefully it should work now as you are using anaconda 3 as the interpreter instead of the default one.

Comment: I tried to use cx_freeze in the begining and it went bad. But after asking,  tnx to everyone finaly It went well after a long search in Github.I found this repository ,-brentvollebregt
/auto-py-to-exe -- > and its worked like magic .